# How to return to a Parent Activity from a sub activity when using Tabs in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-activity

I have two tabs A, B with corresponding TabActivityA and TabActivityB. I have a third ActivityA1 which is not on the tab but is an intermediate activity coming from ActivityA.

Here is the code in sequence

```
 public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Home
        TabSpec homeSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Home");
        homeSpec.setIndicator("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_home_tab));
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, TabActivityA.class);
        homeSpec.setContent(homeIntent);


        // Tab for my cases
        TabSpec helppec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Help");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        helppec.setIndicator("Help", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_cases_tab));
        Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, TabActivityB.class);
        mycasesspec.setContent(helpIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(homeSpec); // Adding home tab
        tabHost.addTab(help); // Adding help tab

    }

ActivityA1 extends Activity
{
}

TabActivityA extends ActivityGroup
{
.....
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA1.class);
 View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ActivityA1",  nextScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP)).getDecorView(); 
 setContentView(view);
}
```

Note: I am doing this because I want to show the same tabs for ActivityA1

This does show the tab (Home and Help) on ActivityA1, however on clicking the Home tab I want the user to go to TabActivityA but right now it is staying on ActivityA1 only.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: could you explain your question clearly

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand what you are asking now, simply keep an arrayList of View, add to this list before you call SetContentView, then when you are ready to go back to the previous View do SetContentView(list[count - 1]), also make sure you remove the previous View and dispose of it or it will hang around in memory forever...

Comment: This is what I am currently doing and I tried with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP as well. This does result in showing the tabs on ActivityA1 however my question is that how do I go back from this ActivityA1 to TabActivityA?